# Globally enable authentication in ServiceStack, except for some requests

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Using [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), I have to selectively [enable authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) on services, request DTOs and actions by applying the `[Authenticate]` attribute on the respective classes/methods.

Is it possible to do the inverse? I.e. globally enable authentication for all services/requests and then selectively disable authentication for some requests (e.g. using something like a `[NoAuthentication]` attribute on the relevant parts)?

Answer (score 4):

Create a Request Filter Attribute that sets a flag in the request context saying to skip authentication:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NoAuthenticateAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {

    public NoAuthenticateAttribute() : this(ApplyTo.All) {}

    public NoAuthenticateAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo) : base(applyTo) {
        // execute this before any AuthenticateAttribute executes.
        // https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations
        Priority = this.Priority = ((int) RequestFilterPriority.Authenticate) - 1;
    }

    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        req.Items["SkipAuthentication"] = true;
    }
}
```

And create a custom subclass of `AuthenticateAttribute` that checks for that flag in the request:

```cs
public class MyAuthenticateAttribute : AuthenticateAttribute {
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (!ShouldSkipAuthenticationFor(req))
            base.Execute(req, res, requestDto);
    }

    private bool ShouldSkipAuthenticationFor(IHttpRequest req)
    {
        return req.Items.ContainsKey("SkipAuthentication");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
[MyAuthenticate]
public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Get(DtoThatNeedsAuthentication obj)
    {
        // this will be authenticated
    }

    [NoAuthenticate]
    public object Get(DtoThatShouldNotAuthenticate obj)
    {
        // this will not be authenticated
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I up voted this answer, the solution didn't work for me. It calls the MyAuthenticate attribute only and fails to call the NoAuthenticate attribute.

Comment: @theoutlander You mean the Execute method in the NoAuthenticateAttribute class is not invoked? Where are you applying your MyAuthenticate and NoAuthenticate attributes?